# PySide.QtGui.QImage to Base64

Tags: python, base64, pyside, qtgui, qimage

Apologies for the novice question, but can not find solution. You know as PySide.QtGui.QImage convert a base64 image or get the data to a string?

I tried this

> image_data = base64.b64encode (imageActual)

but I get this error

> TypeError: must be string or buffer, not PySide.QtGui.QImage

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Convert to base64:

```
    img = QtGui.QImage('image.png')
    ba = QtCore.QByteArray()
    buffer = QtCore.QBuffer(ba)
    buffer.open(QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
    img.save(buffer, 'PNG')
    base64_data = ba.toBase64().data()
```

Convert from base64:

```
    ba = QtCore.QByteArray.fromBase64(base64_data)
    img = QtGui.QImage.fromData(ba, 'PNG')
```

Comment: I can't get the convert from base64 to work. I always get an empty byte array. Not sure what is going wrong. The data is fine, I tried it online and got the image.

Comment: @ZohaibZaidi. Can't really comment without seeing the actual data that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem using this :

```
image_64_decode = base64.decodestring(base64Data)
image = QtGui.QImage()
image.loadFromData(image_64_decode , 'PNG')
```